# What is the reasonable max number of features for LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I've been trying to find information on how many features I can use in LSTM.
I found that LSTM can handle up to 500-1000 timesteps, but what about features (sequences)?

Can I use 1000 features per timestep?

What is the working maximum and what affects that number? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is no maximum or reasonable amount of features for LSTM layers in general. Everything is extremely task specific.

Before training an LSTM model with that amount of variables you'd encounter a number of practical problems, for example:

1. Prohibitive computational costs. I don't think any machine could handle that without crashing.
2. Its need of massive amounts of data. Such a model would require a dataset of unimaginable size, in order to be trained properly.

But that said, practical problems apart, there is no theoretical threshold to the number of features you can feed into RNNs.

Comment: Does it mean that features don't intersect/interfere in the hidden state/output calculation? I.e. the increase in the number of features results in a linear increase in the number of hidden states and outputs?